# Create MSI from extracted setup files

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I have a folder with a 3rd party installer, the folder contains a setup.exe and all its CAB files next to it (and many related folders).

[image: folder content]

I want to be able to re-package this 3rd party installer into something that I can use in my main application installer as a prerequisite (or as a chained msi package).

I want to not just extract/copy those files on the client machine, but run the installer.

Is it possible to create a MSI from all those files using Installshield? I can't seem to find a project type that would do it.

Comment: Checking in to see if you found a viable option?

Comment: Not yet, on vacations right now, but I will look at your long answer below.

Comment: I would just install it in silent mode using a suite project applying the suitable silent response files. Multi-lingual setups do not generally repackage / capture well.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I did not find a solution; I will try to see if I can re-activate our Installshield support.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul one suggestion I got was to use the prerequisite editor, but it does not support folders, only files in a single folder.

Comment: If all you want is to run this setup in silent mode, I suppose you should try the [Installshield Suite project feature](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/SteCreatingSuites.htm) first of all. I am not sure about its details, but you should be able to run things in sequence and handle error conditions. I don't have the tool available to test if it can handle folders. But [here is a screen shot of the suite project in action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49212599/129130).

Comment: this is more or less what I want to do : https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?217900-Setup-Prerequisite-folder-structures

Answer (score 1):

***Problem Scenario***: What is your scenario?

- Are you taking over the handling and update of an old setup and need to convert it to a proper format?
- Are you trying to re-package a third party vendor setup.exe?
- Are you trying to get hold of the files inside the CABs? Or just to extract the files so they can be re-packaged some other way. For some reason?
- Are you trying to install the whole shebang as easily and reliably as possibly in silent mode?
- Some other problem scenario?

---

***Silent Running?***: If what you need is to just install silently, then there are command line switches for most **`setup.exe`** wrappers that will let you do this, but it is different for every tool used to create the `setup.exe` file. Installshield's setup.exe files require a silent response file, other tools do it differently. [I wrote about Installshield silent uninstall a couple of days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865252/uninstalling-an-installshield-installscript-msi-program-using-c-sharp-silently/51869939#51869939). And [here is a piece on regular silent install and various types of Installshield setup.exe files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48976617/regarding-silent-installation-using-setup-exe-generated-using-installshield-2013).

Record response file:

```
Setup.exe /r /f1”c:\temp\my-answer-file.iss”
```

Basic silent install:

```
Setup.exe /s /f1”c:\temp\my-answer-file.iss”
```

If the `setup.exe` is a wrapper for an MSI and you have a distribution system to rely on to distribute the pre-requisite components, then it is generally better to extract the MSI if you are in a corporate environment and use the standard features in MSI to run silently (the **`/QN`** switch for **`msiexec.exe`**):

```
msiexec.exe /I "C:\Your.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\msilog.log" TRANSFORMS="C:\1031.mst;C:\My.mst"
```

Quick Parameter Explanation:

```
/I = run install sequence
/QN = run completely silently
/L*V "C:\msilog.log" = verbose logging
TRANSFORMS="C:\1031.mst;C:\My.mst" = Apply transforms 1031.mst and My.mst (see below).
```

---

***File Extraction?***: Getting the files out of a **`setup.exe`** can be challenging, or very easy. It depends what it was built with, and that can be pretty much "anything" - from established deployment tools to proprietary software made by "anyone". To extract files from various types of **`setup.exe`** you can find extensive information in this answer:

- [Extract MSI from EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512) (a plethora of links on the subject)
- There is also Michael Urman's "hand's-on": [Programmatically extract contents of InstallShield setup.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681252/programmatically-extract-contents-of-installshield-setup-exe/8694205#8694205)

Essentially you use **`setup.exe /stage_only`** for Installshield Suite executables. And **`setup.exe /a`** for Basic MSI and Installscript MSI executables. And **`setup.exe /s /extract_all`** for legacy Installscript executables. Clarifications below.

> ***MSI Import***: If you manage to extract the files and you see an MSI file there,
>   then you should be able to import or open that MSI file in
>   Installshield (or other deployment tools as well).

---

I'll try a quick "short-list" of extraction options (not sure if that is what you really need):

***Already an MSI?***: Do you know what that **`setup.exe`** contains? Technically it could already be a wrapper containing an MSI file, or it could be the output of some legacy deployment tool and not be a Windows Installer at all. Let's just list a few options:

1. [***Administrative Installation***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564619/what-is-the-purpose-of-administrative-installation-initiated-using-msiexec-a/5751980#5751980): Try to do a **`setup.exe /a`** from a command prompt to see if you get an "extract files" dialog. If so, specify an output location and extract all files. This indicates an MSI setup wrapped in a setup.exe
2. ***Installscript setup***: Try to do a **`setup.exe /s /extract_all`** from a command prompt to see if you can extract files from the CABs. This is for Installscript setups. Or try **`/extract_all:[path]`** as well.
3. ***[Installshield](http://www.installshield.com) Suite Setups***: Try to do a **`setup.exe /stage_only`** from a command prompt. [Lots of elaborate details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48976617/regarding-silent-installation-using-setup-exe-generated-using-installshield-2013/49011371#49011371).
4. ***[Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com)***: Try to do **`setup.exe /extract "C:\My work"`** or  **`setup.exe /x`**
5. ***[WiX](http://www.wixtoolset.com)***: Try the following from a command prompt: **`dark.exe -x outputfolder setup.exe`**. A WiX setup.exe file can only be extracted using the dark.exe tool from the framework itself. In other words you need to install WiX to extract a WiX setup.exe (as of now).
6. ***[Wise](https://www.itninja.com/blog/view/wise-setup-exe-switches)***: Wise is no longer marketed, but many older setups remain. You can try to extract files with **`setup.exe /X [path]`**.
7. ***[Repackaging](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/admins.htm)***: One way to create an MSI package from older-style, legacy setup.exe installers, is to "capture" the changes done to the system by using an [Application Repackaging Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221983/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-run-through-an-installer/46224987#46224987) which monitors changes made to the system whilst a setup.exe is being run.

It is impossible to cover all the different kinds of possible setup.exe files. They might feature all kinds of different command line switches. [There are so many possible tools that can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624070/how-to-create-windows-installer/49632260#49632260). ([**`non-MSI`**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/tt_nonmsi.htm),[**`MSI`**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/authoring.htm), [**`admin-tools`**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/admins.htm), [**`multi-platform`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619358/does-an-universal-cross-platform-installer-exists/51624645#51624645), etc...).

Commmon tools such as `Inno Setup` seems to make extraction hard ([unofficial unpacker](http://innounp.sourceforge.net/), not tried by me, run by virustotal). Whereas `NSIS` seems to use regular archives that standard archive software can open.

***General Tricks***: One trick is to launch the setup.exe and look in the **1) system's temp folder** for extracted files. Another trick is to  use **2) 7-Zip, WinRAR, WinZip** or similar archive tools to see if they can read the format. Some claim success by **3) opening the setup.exe in Visual Studio**. Not a technique I use.

---

***Some Links***:

- [How do I extract an InstallShield Cabinet file?](https://superuser.com/questions/88645/how-do-i-extract-an-installshield-cabinet-file) (this I have never tried)
- [Uninstall and Install App on my Computer silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422777/uninstall-and-install-app-on-my-computer-silently/49600406#49600406)
- [How to make better use of MSI files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458857/how-to-make-better-use-of-msi-files/1055861#1055861)

Comment: I'm trying to "Are you trying to re-package a third party vendor setup.exe?"; 
I will edit my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an InstallShield noob looking for help with a similar problem, but for your needs a Basic MSI Project should be sufficient.

If you are using the Project Assistant wizard, when you the get to the Application Files section you drag-and-drop your various folders and the setup.exe into the INSTALLDIR folder in the wizard and that's pretty much it, I think.

As I recall from other issues I had creating a non-installing MSI of SQL Server, Install Shield will automatically recognize your setup.exe and run that when the .MSI is run.

Comment: " Install Shield will automatically recognize your setup.exe and run that when the .MSI is run."  Whooaaa, will try it.

Answer (score 0):

> That sort of looks like a **legacy Installshield `setup.exe`** OR an
>   **Installscript MSI `setup.exe`**. Despite similar appearances these are very different beasts.
>
> I would try the following to determine what you are dealing with:
>
> ```
> setup.exe /a
> ```
>
> If you get a dialog asking you for an output folder you probably have
>   an Installscript MSI. Extract the files and then look for an MSI in
>   the output folder.
>
> If that does not work try `setup.exe /s /extract_all` or `setup.exe /extract_all:[path]`. Or [try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24033894/129130).

---

***Installshield Suite Project***: Seeing as you want to distribute this setup as part of your own application deployment I would probably use an **Installshield Suite Project** - if you have a license for an Installshield version that supports this project type. [See screen shot here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190377/msi-build-uninstall-installed-directory-not-removing/49212599#49212599).

The **`Silent_Install.bat`** file (and the associated **`Silent_Uninstall.bat`** for uninstall) should contain the command lines you need to use when inserting the package into the suite project. Then you also include your own application as part of the suite installation. Makes sure to test well in all deployment scenarios: install, upgrade, modify, uninstall, patch, etc... There are always surprises.

***Repackaging***: Alternatively you could re-package the setup with a capture tool instead of running it "as is" - in the existing format. Then you essentially "record" changes made by the setup by monitoring its installation. This works in most cases, but requires significant knowledge to clean up properly. **`There are also challenges for multi-lingual setups - which this appears to be`**. This approach has been extensively used in corporations to convert legacy installers to MSI format - and it is still in use. The end result is an MSI that can be installed in silent mode in the standard Windows Installer fashion (which is reliable - much more so than a legacy setup.exe run in silent mode). I would still wrap the captured MSI in a suite project, although you in principle could add it to your own product's MSI. I would not recommend this - for several reasons. Most significantly that you could need to update the runtime setup on its own - without rebuilding your own MSI.