# How to get Installshield SplashBitmap image for wix?

Tags: image, wix, windows-installer, installation, bmp

I need InstallShield msi background image to use in wix.
I have extracted msi via 7zip but I couldn't find background image. Can anyone help me to find it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***Copyright***: Not sure about the copyright issues involved, I definitely would use my own images, but if you just want to get the images for the size parameters and then modify the content, then maybe just use **`dark.exe`** to decompile the MSI to its constituent parts. See link below for WiX's own, default images on [github.com](https://www.github.com).

***Dark.exe***: With WiX installed ([WiX quick start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130)) you can de-compile any (or at least most) MSI files to see what it contains by using the **`dark.exe`** binary and specify to extract binaries using the **`/x`** switch (this assumes **`dark.exe`** is in the path, or else use full path to it):

```
dark.exe "YourSetup.msi" /x Bins
```

The above command creates a decompiled **WXS WiX source file** in the main MSI folder and a sub folder called **Bin** with extracted binaries from within the MSI (if the command completes without error).

***WiX's Own Bitmaps***: You can find WiX's own, default bitmaps here: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/Bitmaps

---

***Setup.exe Extraction***: If your MSI is embedded in a **`setup.exe`**, first try **`setup.exe /a`** - that should work for all or at least most Installshield setups.

If that does not work, please see these answers for extraction approaches:

- [Create MSI from extracted setup files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932661/create-msi-from-extracted-setup-files/51941558#51941558) (towards bottom)
- [What is the purpose of administrative installation initiated using msiexec /a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564619/what-is-the-purpose-of-administrative-installation-initiated-using-msiexec-a/5751980#5751980)
- [Extract MSI from EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512)