# Typo in wix uninstall dialog

Tags: c#, installation, dll, wix, uninstallation

I created a Windows Installer package a few years ago and now I found out that there is a typo.

[image]

I can't find the source code of this dialog to fix this issue.
Is it maybe a known error in the "wix-toolset" or is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: If you put the MSI in an empty folder and run: `dark.exe "YourSetup.msi" /x Bins` - what do you get? Check the source code files. The binaries will be in the sub folder "Bins". [More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814554/how-to-get-installshield-splashbitmap-image-for-wix). Unless you already know where this is coming from. You should also be able to inspect the MSI with Orca and find the word "Unistall", unless the dialog is shown via a custom action and not via MSI GUI tables.

Comment: Just for the record: [Various ways to compare MSI files - the free tools you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files).

Answer (score 1):

That dialog isn't part of WiX. You need to find out where it's coming from (custom Windows Installer dialog or custom action) and fix it there.