# What software created the installer exe for 'Windows Embedded Standard 7' (legacy code) - how to find out?

Tags: installation, windows-installer

We have a legacy exe installer, that our company runs on Windows Embedded Standard 7 to install a program.

We don't know how to re-recreate it since we don't have any source code for it, no project files, etc... just the exe.  We pretty much know what it does:

1. changes to windows registry
2. changes to environment variable
3. changes to windows log
4. changes to windows service

We currently work on VS2019 and wanted to create a similar exe installer in VS2019, but as far as we can tell it only has msi installer.
There are two questions we need to answer:

A. What program or software created the existing SomeName.exe?
B. If we can not figure out what program created the existing one, what open source or free software should we consider to create an exe installer to get the above steps?

Some screenshots of what dialog boxes we encounter upon install/uninstall are attached:

[installation step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcPDP.png)

[installation step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h0AU.png)

Thanks

Comment: The Open Source WiX Toolset allows you to decompile an MSI and re-compile its sources to a new MSI if needed. [Please see this old answer to check if this is relevant for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54815605/129130). The dialog you show looks like an MSI installer, but the MSI is likely wrapped in an EXE launcher. [Please see this answer for details on extracting setup.exe files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987512/129130). And [finally I will throw in this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51941558/129130) (similar answer on file extraction).

Comment: Check the exe/msi installation log. You should able to find the tool using which this exe was created. Also, you could check exe properties that might also be useful.